# Processing multiple modes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I'm obviously dealing with slightly more complex and realistic data, but to showcase my trouble, let's assume we have these data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

purchases_df = pd.DataFrame({"user_id": [100, 101, 100, 101, 200],
                      "date": ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-01','2022-01-01','2022-01-01', '2022-01-01'],
                      "purchase": ['cookies', 'jam', 'jam', 'jam', 'cashews']})
```

I want to find modal values of purchases by date:

```
agg_mode = purchases_df.groupby(['date', 'user_id'])['purchase'].agg(pd.Series.mode)
agg_mode
```

`agg_mode` will show that for `user_id` `100` we have two modal values: `[cookies, jam]`. This is totally fine with me, when it comes to real data we've come up with a set of rules which mode to pick if there's a tie. The **problem** is, to use that heuristic, I need to able to check if the returned set of multiple modal values contains certain values (let's say, if `cookies` and `jam` are returned, we'd always stick to `jam` only.  I can't find a simple way to process returned multimodal values:

```
agg_mode_df = purchases_df.groupby(['date', 'user_id'])['purchase'].agg(pd.Series.mode).to_frame()
agg_mode_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
agg_mode_df
```

`agg_mode_df` is a DataFrame, and the `purchase` column (which now holds the modal values) becomes of `object dtype` with numpy `ndarrays` in case of more than one `mode` for the `user_id`, and I couldn't find a working way to convert the modal value(s) of every single user to a `list`.

Am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
agg_mode = purchases_df.groupby(['date', 'user_id'])['purchase'].agg(lambda x: x.mode().tolist())
```

Comment: A closing parenthesis needs to be added to this, but this looks like the best solution.